# Regex to match string that doesn’t start with 001 or 002

Tags: java, regex

Trying to write Javax validation regex pattern to match any string with the following:

- Doesn’t start with 001, 002 or 003
- Starts with 3 digits followed by a hyphen, which is then followed by any letter, number, hyphen, $, + or _
- Contains 35-50 characters in total

What I have so far which works for the 2nd and 3rd requirements that I listed above:

“^[\w\-+\$_]{35,50}$”

Now I am trying to add the 1st requirement which I listed above, however I cannot seem to get it to work:

”^[?!(001|002|003)\-+\$_]{35,50}$”

Comment: Why is your `001` etc inside a character class?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `String#matches` here with the following regex pattern:

```
^(?!00[123])\d{3}-[A-Za-z0-9$+_-]{35,50}$
```

This uses a negative lookahead at the beginning of the pattern to assert that the input does not begin with `001`, `002`, or `003`.

Sample Java code:

```
String input = "123-12323456780abcdefghij1234567890abcde";
if (input.matches("(?!00[123])\\d{3}-[A-Za-z0-9$+_-]{35,50}")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

Note carefully that when using `String#matches` we don't need the `^` and `$` starting/ending anchors.  This is because `matches()` implicitly applies the input regex pattern against the entire string.